# Does it matter what teams I pick on the final mission?

Tags: saints-row-iv

Needless to say, **spoilers**.

On the final mission, your crew breaks up into teams of 2.  The teams are:

> Matt and Asha
> Pierce and Shaundi
> Ben King and Johnny Gat

They are picked for 3 different tasks.  Does it matter which team does which task?  Can I pick 1 team for multiple tasks?

Comment: I tried several team combinations. Dialogue was different but it didn't fundamentally affect the outcome. I mean you can still beat the game. It isn't like Mass Effect 2 where your choices can cause people to die. SR4 isn't a game of harsh realities where choices have consequences. You can murder entire city blocks and police stop chasing you after 1 minute...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the main differences in the [Grand Finale](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Finale) mission that depends on which team you chose are dialog changes with the homies. Each team has different dialog for each of the mission parts. There are no significant gameplay differences that I noticed.

In the second part of the mission, in the part where (quoting [Saints Row Wiki](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Finale#Gameplay)) "*things from those homies nightmares come through but are friendly*" - this will depend on the team you chose. It's not a big effect on the gameplay though, as you will leave that area shortly afterwards for your next objective.

Also, a mission part might be easier depending on which [homies' loyalty missions](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Missions_in_Saints_Row_IV#Loyalty) you have finished (which homies have been transformed into their super-powered versions in the simulation). Super-powered homies will make finishing a mission part a little bit easier.

If you haven't finished all loyalty missions before starting the Grand Finale mission, IMO, you should prioritize choosing the super-powered homies that you currently have for the second part, and then the first part. In the third part, your homies will not be using their super powers, even if they have them. While the first part does not really require much from your homies (they will mostly just be driving a vehicle).

You can only pick one team per task / mission part. Once chosen for a mission part, a team can not be chosen for another mission part. I recommend saving before starting the mission, if you want to replay the mission parts with a different team.

#### Game Ending

Another factor that could affect the outcome of this mission is which [homies' loyalty missions](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Missions_in_Saints_Row_IV#Loyalty) you have finished *before* playing the mission (rather than which team you chose). Because about this mission's ending...

> There are two endings to this mission, though it is not through anything the player does in the mission. If all loyalty quests are completed, then the player will unlock the true ending where the Saints discover time travel and the narrator will be revealed to be Jane Austen. If not all the loyalty quests are completed, then the player gets the non-canonical "bad ending" of the game in which the Saints do not discover time travel and the player will not get the "Saints and Sensibility" achievement.

<sup>Source: [Saints Row Wiki, "Grand Finale - Trivia"](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Finale)</sup>

Comment: It may be possible that whether you've taken the time to superpower the homies in question affects the outcome somehow, but I'd have to replay most of the game to test that hypothesis.

Comment: @Shadur I think you're right. Editing what I found out into my answer.

Comment: You actually do not need to do all a homie's missions for them to get powers.  Each one has 1 mission that, upon completion, gives them powers.  Also, for the "special" ending, you just need all your homies to have super powers.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. Just make sure you have finished all loyalties...